# How to select the item from the dropdown using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu, display

Having difficulty to select a item from drop down. HTML:

```
<div id="first4" class="ui-small ui-re-row-sapce">                          
<select name="srclang" id="srclang" data-placeholder="Type source language *" class="form-control del-change capturedata selectized" tabindex="-1" style="display: none;"><option value="90" selected="selected">English</option></select>

<input type="select-one" autocomplete="off" tabindex="" id="srclang-selectized" placeholder="Type source language *" style="width: 151px; opacity: 1; position: relative; left: 0px;">
```

Code trials:

```
Select SourceLanguageIs= new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='srclang-selectized']"))); 
SourceLanguageIs.selectByIndex(2); 
//SourceLanguageIs.selectByVisibleText("English"); // 
SourceLanguageIs.selectByValue("90");
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the HTML it seems the `<select>` node is having the attribute `style="display: none;"` so you can't directly access the `<select>` node.

You can pass the partial relevant *character sequence* i.e. **English** to the `<input>` tag and then `click()` on the element with text as **English** and you can use the following solution:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@id='srclang-selectized']"))).sendKeys("English");
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//select[@id='srclang' and @name='srclang']/option[contains(., 'English')]"))).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ignore the Select class because the 'select' tag line is invisible and Try the below code:

```
driver.findElement(By.id('srclang-selectized')).sendKeys("Option that you want to Select");
```

As it is an id so no need to write an XPath expression.

Comment: `select` is not an attribute, perhaps `select` node.

Comment: @DebanjanB, Yeah, it is a tag.

Answer (score 0):

The following are the most common methods used on to select drop down list.

1. selectByVisibleText()
2. selectByValue()
3. selectByIndex()

Sample code to select the drop down as follows:

```
Select SourceLanguageIs= new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("srclang")));
SourceLanguageIs.selectByIndex(2); 
SourceLanguageIs.selectByVisibleText("English");
SourceLanguageIs.selectByValue("90");
```

Hopes it helped out .